# Solving $x^3 - 3x - \sqrt{2} = 0$ using $x=k\cos\theta$ and $\cos 3\theta = 4 \cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

I have proved the first part of this problem, but am stuck.

> Prove 
>   $$\cos 3\theta = 4 \cos^3 \theta - 3 \cos \theta$$
>
> Hence solve the equation
>
> $$x^3 - 3x - \sqrt{2} = 0$$
>
> by using a suitable substitution of the form $x = k \cos\theta$, then finding possible values of $\theta$ between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$  Give your answers in surd form.

I am working through an A level maths course.  I am studying on my own and have looked at the answer in the book which tells me $k = 2$. I don’t know how this was established but can see that using this we can show $\cos 3θ$ = $1/\sqrt{2}$.

But I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Please format your mathematical expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, in the equation $x^3-3x-\sqrt2=0$, you do the substitution $x=2y$, you get $8y^3-6y-\sqrt2=0$, which is equivalent to $4y^3-3y-\frac{\sqrt2}2=0$. But $\frac{\sqrt2}2=\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)$. So, take $\theta=\frac\pi{12}$ and use the fact that$$4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=\cos(3\theta)=\frac{\sqrt2}2.$$

Comment: Thanks.  But how does that solve the equation? My book gives the answers as - √2 , 1/2(√2 + √6), 1/2(√2 - √6)

Comment: It follows from what I did that the solutions are $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)$, $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{2\pi}3\right)$, and $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac{4\pi}3\right)$. Using trigonometriy, you can prove that these numbers are $\frac12\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt6\right)$, $-\sqrt2$, and $\frac12\left(\sqrt2-\sqrt6\right)$ respectively.

Comment: I follow most of your reasoning but how do we get from saying  $\theta=\frac\pi{12}$ to finding $2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)$ as a solution?

Comment: Since $4\cos^3\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)-3\cos\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, $\cos\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)$ is a solution of the equation $4y^3-3y=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. Therefore, $2\cos\left(\frac\pi{12}\right)$ is a solution of the original equation.